# Install ruby 2.7.3 on Mac M1 issue

Tags: macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon, openproject

When I try to install the ruby 2.7.3 version on mac m1 it installs, it shows in my machine also but when I try sudo **bin/setup_dev** this command its show me error like

```
Bundling rails dependencies Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on
this machine. Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.7.3
bin/setup_dev: 
Failed to run 'bundle install > log/setup_dev.log', check log/setup_dev.log for more information.
aim@aim-MacBook-Air openproject % rbenv global 2.7.3
aim@aim-MacBook-Air openproject % ruby -v                                         
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

please any one can help to install ruby v 2.7.3 on mac.
Things that I try

> Install ruby using **rosetta 2**

I am new on ruby please help on this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a ruby version in a bundler gemfile doesn’t magically install that version of ruby. You need to start by learning to use a ruby version management system. I recommend Homebrew and rbenv.

(And not just in order to get a different ruby version. Always install your own ruby. Never use the built in system ruby for anything! If you have to say sudo you’re doing it wrong.)